# My UISearchbar & search display controller isn't working properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

This is the hierarchy of the controls 
[image]

This is when i tap on searchbar textfield (everything is normal here)
[image]

But when i type, this is how the results are displayed. there is a gap between searchbar and table header where cells are visible.
[image]

And also, when i rotate while searching this happens to searchbar. Though xcode isn't allowing adding constraints from the autolayout menu on bottom.
[image]

Comment: not sure about the rotation issue, but the gap is controlled by the         `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property of the root view controller

Comment: @LeonidUsov i'm pretty sure that one is unchecked already from attribute inspector

Comment: please see if it is set in any of the enclosing view controllers. For me it was not the direct parent view controller, but one above it